# Unable to use user-defined object class in Apache DS Studio

Tags: ldap, apacheds

I defined an object class and want to use it in my `organizationalUnit`. But as I attached the screenshot, I can't see my object class(**aibu-staff**) in the entry list.

[image]

**When I try to import LDIF file into DIT, getting an error like this:**

```
Error while importing LDIF
 - [LDAP: error code 53 - UNWILLING_TO_PERFORM: failed for     Add Request 
  javax.naming.OperationNotSupportedException: [LDAP: error code 53 - UNWILLING_TO_PERFORM: failed for     Add Request :
ClientEntry
    dn: cn=aibu, ou=schema
    objectclass: metaSchema
    objectclass: top
    cn: aibu
    m-dependencies: system
    m-dependencies: cosine
    m-dependencies: nis
    m-dependencies: inetorgperson
    m-dependencies: core
: Unwilling to perform operation on enabled schema with disabled or missing dependencies: nis]; remaining name 'cn=aibu, ou=schema'
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.mapErrorCode(LdapCtx.java:3160)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:3033)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:2840)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.c_createSubcontext(LdapCtx.java:811)
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.ComponentDirContext.p_createSubcontext(ComponentDirContext.java:337)
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.createSubcontext(PartialCompositeDirContext.java:266)
    at org.apache.directory.studio.connection.core.io.jndi.JNDIConnectionWrapper$4.run(JNDIConnectionWrapper.java:658)
    at org.apache.directory.studio.connection.core.io.jndi.JNDIConnectionWrapper.runAndMonitor(JNDIConnectionWrapper.java:1272)
    at org.apache.directory.studio.connection.core.io.jndi.JNDIConnectionWrapper.checkConnectionAndRunAndMonitor(JNDIConnectionWrapper.java:1203)
    at org.apache.directory.studio.connection.core.io.jndi.JNDIConnectionWrapper.createEntry(JNDIConnectionWrapper.java:704)
    at org.apache.directory.studio.ldapbrowser.core.jobs.ImportLdifJob.importLdifRecord(ImportLdifJob.java:457)
    at org.apache.directory.studio.ldapbrowser.core.jobs.ImportLdifJob.importLdif(ImportLdifJob.java:267)
    at org.apache.directory.studio.ldapbrowser.core.jobs.ImportLdifJob.executeNotificationJob(ImportLdifJob.java:204)
    at org.apache.directory.studio.ldapbrowser.core.jobs.AbstractNotificationJob.executeAsyncJob(AbstractNotificationJob.java:43)
    at org.apache.directory.studio.ldapbrowser.core.jobs.AbstractEclipseJob.run(AbstractEclipseJob.java:101)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)

  [LDAP: error code 53 - UNWILLING_TO_PERFORM: failed for     Add Request :
ClientEntry
    dn: cn=aibu, ou=schema
    objectclass: metaSchema
    objectclass: top
    cn: aibu
    m-dependencies: system
    m-dependencies: cosine
    m-dependencies: nis
    m-dependencies: inetorgperson
    m-dependencies: core
: Unwilling to perform operation on enabled schema with disabled or missing dependencies: nis]
```

Answer (score 0):

Windows has a [poss-Superiors attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679133%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that defines what kind of objects that can be the parent of an object.  You might need to add organizational unit.

Comment: My Apache DS is running on Linux.

Comment: by the way I've just updated first post; added the error that happens while trying to import LDIF file into DIT.

Comment: @talha06 I'm confused, have you successfully created your custom class (can you see it in the schema OU)?  If not, then update your question with the LDIF file that's not working.

Comment: yeah I have created my custom class in a schema project but I can't use it; getting an error while trying to import LDIF file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to refresh the schema object before you can see the user defined object. I was always able to do this without any problems. (Programmatically using JNDI as well).

Comment: I'm using Apache DS Studio 2.0M8.

Comment: how did you add the objectclass and attributes to apacheds?

Comment: I created online Schema Project; then created custom attributes and objectclasses.